# What's the current (as of April 2010) state of affairs regarding <object> vs <embed> in HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, cross-browser, embed, embedded-resource

The age old question. `<object>` vs `<embed>`. From what I gather, `<object>` is the XHTML-compliant way of doing things, while `<embed>` is for legacy support. I'm currently building a Flash application that will contain a pre-made embedding code for users to copy and paste, and I'm wondering if it's feasible to simply dump the `<embed>` tag altogether.

Which browsers would be unable to load my application if I gave my users an `<object>`-only embed code?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML4/XHTML1 only knows `<object>` and `<applet>` for the embedding of multimedia content, though the `<embed>` tag like the `<object>` is supported by all common browsers AFAIK.

With HTML5 `<embed>` will be included in the specification (in addition to the `<object>` tag), whereas the `<applet>` is going to be removed. In addition, there will be new tags like `<audio>`, `<canvas>`, `<svg>` and `<video>`.

As far as I understand the HTML5 specs, flash contents can be included with both - `<embed>` and `<object>`.